# Create a bootable USB flash drive on a different computer

Tags: boot, liveusb

How do you create a bootable flash drive from a computer and then use it to boot another computer?  I need to do this because my computer is not booting, so I can't create one.
Im on windows 8 by the way

Comment: So what do you want? A bootable flash with live OS so you can fix your system, or you want to have something else on that USB?

Comment: I want to boot, get my files backed up, and reinstall my OS

Comment: So you need a live OS then. You can use any live Linux distro for that or if you have any other live OS. I'm using Ultra ISO as it can burn an image file to USB or HDD. In the Main menu, select Bootable -> Write Disk Image...and select the USB drive you want to make bootable. Now you can boot from that USB and backup your data

Comment: You first need to ascertain *why* it won't boot. E.g. if the harddisk is broken, booting from USB won't get it back... Does the computer show anything when you turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Linux live OS in a bootable USB as suggested in a comment to your question.

You can create it it any Windows computer and use it in any other Windows computer.

You can use any Linux distribution of your choice. For example you can use Ubuntu and follow the step-by-step instructions in [this simple tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

#### STEPS:

1. Download Ubuntu .iso from the [official website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
2. Download and install [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and follow the instructions.
3. Insert the bootable USB into your computer and run boot setting to boot from the USB first.
4. Backup your files through Ubuntu.

If you have trouble using Ubuntu you can always ask a question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Note that this may work for you in the case that your Windows is not working properly but your hardware does not present any problem... If your PC is not booting because a hardware failure this will not work!